# Unable to open JMeter 2.11 JMX script in Jmeter 3.2

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to open JMX which loads and runs fine in JMeter 2.11 but its failing with below errors when I am trying to open it in Jmeter 3.2

```
2017-04-14 14:39:39,515 ERROR o.a.j.t.g.TestBeanGUI: This should never happen!
java.lang.Error: null
    at org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.gui.TestBeanGUI.<init>(TestBeanGUI.java:159) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getGuiFromCache(GuiPackage.java:393) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getGui(GuiPackage.java:245) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getGui(GuiPackage.java:216) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addComponent(JMeterTreeModel.java:145) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:121) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:121) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:121) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:113) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.addSubTree(GuiPackage.java:517) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:194) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:131) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.LoadRecentProject.doActionAfterCheck(LoadRecentProject.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.doAction(AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.java:45) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:74) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:59) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
```

Comment: JMeter 3.2 just got released today. Please check the JAVA prerequisites and validate the bin files in 3.2 folder. Try to run in 3.1 and let me know.

Comment: I am not seeing download link on http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi where can I download 3.1?

Comment: Here is the link to download 3.1 http://download.nextag.com/apache//jmeter/binaries/

Comment: Also JMeter 3.2 runs on Java 8 or later. Please check here http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi

Comment: Hello, Any feedback on answer ? If ok it should be accepted and upvote , otherwise you should provide more details

Answer (score 0):

Check release notes to ensure you're not using removed elements.

Check you're not using incompatible plugin.

If issue persists, please open a bug here

- jmeter.apache.org/issues.html

with your test plan attached.